# how should i call a javascript function into a kohana view?

Tags: javascript, view, controller, kohana, call

i am having a simple kohana view, and a javascript that makes a countdown of 30 minutes.
I hava put the javascript file into a directory /media m and its name is countdown.js
 . My problem is: how can i call that javascript? Form the view? Or from the controller to be displayed in the view? and how exactly may i address in a controller or a view that js function or functions?

thank you

the countdown js:

var javascript_countdown = function () {
    var time_left = 10; //number of seconds for countdown
    var output_element_id = 'javascript_countdown_time';
    var keep_counting = 1;
    var no_time_left_message = 'No time left for JavaScript countdown!';

```
function countdown() {
    if(time_left < 2) {
        keep_counting = 0;
    }

    time_left = time_left - 1;
}

function add_leading_zero(n) {
    if(n.toString().length < 2) {
        return '0' + n;
    } else {
        return n;
    }
}

function format_output() {
    var hours, minutes, seconds;
    seconds = time_left % 60;
    minutes = Math.floor(time_left / 60) % 60;
    hours = Math.floor(time_left / 3600);

    seconds = add_leading_zero( seconds );
    minutes = add_leading_zero( minutes );
    hours = add_leading_zero( hours );

    return hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
}

function show_time_left() {
    document.getElementById(output_element_id).innerHTML = format_output();//time_left;
}

function no_time_left() {
    document.getElementById(output_element_id).innerHTML = no_time_left_message;
}

return {
    count: function () {
        countdown();
        show_time_left();
    },
    timer: function () {
        javascript_countdown.count();

        if(keep_counting) {
            setTimeout("javascript_countdown.timer();", 1000);
        } else {
            no_time_left();
        }
    },
    init: function (t, element_id) {
        time_left = t;
        output_element_id = element_id;
        javascript_countdown.timer();
    }
};
```

}();

//time to countdown in seconds, and element ID
javascript_countdown.init(3673, 'javascript_countdown_time');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [kohana html helpers](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/helpers/html#script). In your controller function or your view file, you can have it like this :

```
echo html::script('media/countdown.js');
```

Place the `echo` statement after the html element with id "javascript_countdown_time". Before the closing `</body>` if possible.

```
...
<div id="javascript_countdown_time"></div>
...
<script src="/media/countdown.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: i really can;t figure out how a html helper should look, by readind the contents from that link you gave me.. how can i embed the js script in the html helper?

Comment: the javascript is inside countdown.js. If you want your javascript to be inline, then you could just echo it, Example `echo "<script>window.onload = countdown()</script>"`. I am assuming here you have a countdown() function defined in countdown.js

Comment: so, if i put   echo html::script('mediafiles/countdown.js');
in the controller, and echo "<script>window.onload = countdown()</script>" in the view, the counter doesn't show up at all

Comment: @dana this is assuming you have a countdown function in countdown.js. It would help to post some of the actual code in countdown.js

Comment: ok, it is posted now in the question. my question is: should i echo the html::script('mediafiles.countdown.js') in the controller? That's how the interpreter will know what am i talking about when i'll write <script>window.onload = countdown()</script> in the view? thanks!

Comment: you can do this in the view file, place it before the line `<script>...countdown()</script>`

Comment: it still doesn;t show up.. if i put view source, i get <script type="text/javascript" src="/countdown.js"></script><script>window.onload = show_time_left()</script>

Comment: is `countdown.js` accessible via the browser? While on the page, open `firebug->Console`, type in `show_time_left()`. If you see a `not defined` error, then most likely your `countdown.js` script is not getting loaded.

Comment: if i view page in chrome, i see the link to the js, and if i access it, Kohana_Request_Exception [ 0 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI: mediafiles/countdown.js

Comment: It would be best to follow the kohana filesystem structure for this and use `media/countdown.js` instead. Kohana cannot seem to find your countdown.js. Is `mediafiles` folder in the same level as `index.php`?

Comment: so, now i have the source of the js included in my template, and if i click on it i can see the source, so it;s ok. the question is: how should i call the js from the view? <script>...countdown()</script> doesn't work.

Comment: @dana What about the `window.onload = ...` on my answer, I had it updated 2 hours back? Have you tried this? thanks

Comment: @dana I have edited my answer. Place the `<script>` after loading the html tag that will display the timer. Before end of `</body>` is also a good place to put this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do what @erickb said, or you could do this in your
view (php)

`<script src="media/countdown.js"></script>`

make sure that countdown.js is loaded when the page is displayed in your browser [ use firebug or developer panel in chrome to verify it was loaded. ]

Wherever you wanted to call the functions from , just call it.. Let us know how it went..

Comment: so, i have this in the view: echo html::script('countdown.js');

<script>window.onload = show_time_left()</script>

Comment: did you check from browser whether the countdown.js is loading ?

Comment: yes, if i make view source, i see: <script type="text/javascript" src="/countdown.js"></script><script>window.onload = show_time_left()</script>

Comment: can you click on the countdown.js in the view source you mention ? and does it show a valid countdown.js ?

Comment: no, i can't click on it actually. i really don;t understand why it doesn't load in the view. For simplyfing things, i have put the countdown.js in the view folder, so the path is simple: echo html::script('countdown.js');

Comment: well, sorry, i was in safary. Actually, i can click on it, and the output is Kohana_Request_Exception [ 0 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI: mediafiles/countdown.js

Comment: he he :) do you have the mediafiles folder ? I guess you have wrong path or wrong code.. Do one thing.. Copy this countdown.js to view folder, place one outside view folder, and place one more in parent folder. Now simply replace `echo html::script('countdown.js');` to `<script src="countdown.js"></script>`  
see if it runs

Comment: By doing this, we can know where you have really setup your / to :)

Comment: I am having nearly 7 view files and where actually i should include the script files.Is any separate file is their to include the script and css.How to do it in kohana framework.